# How to calculate the probability of getting a specific value in a random subsample in R?

Tags: r, probability

I have 73 houses categorized as positive (1) or negative (0) for a disease. Each row (73) is a house and only one column with the values.

```
house
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

I would like to know the probability of getting at least one positive (1) if I randomly select 10 houses.

I used the following code:

```
test <- replicate(1000, sample(house, size=10, replace = FALSE))
m <- sum(colSums(matrix(test %in% c("1"), nrow = 10)) > 0)
m/1000

m
[1] 0.909
```

I got a probability of +/- 0.90

Then I used the function *prop.test* to obtain the Confidence Intervals

```
prop.test(m, 1000, conf.level=0.95, correct = FALSE)

1-sample proportions test without continuity correction

data:  m out of 1000, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 669.12, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.8895744 0.9252953
sample estimates:
    p 
0.909
```

I would like to know if with this procedure I can affirm that **the probability of getting at least 1 positive in a sample of 10 is 0.909 (CI 0.890 - 0.9250)**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the MathWorld article [Hypergeometric distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricDistribution.html).  Specifically, the answer is expressed as the hypergeometric distribution's survival function.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're going to post code that involves random sampling, please make sure to set a seed so that others can follow your footsteps:

```
set.seed(8675309)
```

I don't mean to be snarky, but the way this question is phrased makes it difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to learn here.

You've given us some data, and have asked about computing a specific probability, but it's unclear if you're trying to perform inference on some population or are simply interested in computing the probability you asked about.

It's certainly possible to use sampling techniques to estimate the probability here, but that's akin to buying an entire Lego set just to get a few specific pieces.

Based on your question, I think I counted 15 "positives" in your list of houses.  You simply need to calculate:

```
1 - phyper(0, 15, 73-15, 10)

0.916019
```

And this is the probability you're interested in (at least one positive from a n=10 sample).  Also - note that this number *doesn't have "variability"*.  It's the probability, plain and simple; there is no "uncertainty" about it.  With that in mind, is this probability *really what you're after?*  Or are you trying to infer the probability of 1+ "positive" from some theoretical population?  Are the 73 houses a *sample from that population*?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Sorry about the set.seed. Replying to some of your questions I think this is the probability I'm looking for and the 73 houses are my whole population.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question on probabilities. In your case it is about the hypergeometric distribution, which can be answered analitically with

```
phyper(1-0.5,length(dat[dat==1]),length(dat[dat==0]),10,lower.tail=F)
[1] 0.916019
```

This is the probability of getting at least 1 ball with label "1".

Comment: Thanks for the help!